# Constraint parametric letter rendering given width, height and stroke

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, solver, typography

**Problem background:** I am working on a monospaced parametric font, which allows for rendering letters of different styles by tweaking a set of parameters.

**Specific problem:** Given a rectangular region of ***W*** width and ***H*** height and given a stroke width ***S*** what should be the width of a horizontal projection/intersection ***X*** of stroke when rendering letter 'V'?
The letter is *constrained* by the rectangular region and cannot overlap or escape it in any fashion. The letter is symmetrical. I am not bothered by extreme argument values that would make the letter unrenderable.

[image]

**My thoughts:** Does this involve some sort of geometric constraint solver leading to an approximate solution based on a number of iterations?

**Answer expectation:** General direction on a class of the problem, ideally some formulas. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let denote length of low empty segment as

```
p = (w-x)/2
so
x = w - 2 * p
```

Look at annotated drawing - triangles ABC and DFA are similar right-angled ones with similar acute angles ^CAB and ^ADF, AB=h, AD=x, FD=s, BC=p)

[image]

So we can see that ratio of `h` to hypotenuse is the same as ratio of `s` and `x` (it is cosine of acute angle in left low triangle).

```
h / Sqrt(h^2 + p^2) = s / x = s / (w - 2 * p)
h^2 / (h^2 + p^2) = s^2 / (w^2 - 4 * w * p + 4 * p^2)
h^2 * (w^2 - 4 * w * p + 4 * p^2) = s^2 * (h^2 + p^2)
h^2 * w^2 - 4 * w * h^2 * p + 4 * h^2 * p^2 = s^2 * h^2 + s^2 * p^2
p^2 * (4 * h^2 - s^2) - p * (4 * w * h^2 ) + h^2 * (w^2 - s^2) = 0
```

Now we have quadratic equation for unknown p. Choose reliable `p` root value (positive and less than `w/2`) and calculate `x`

For example, `h=4; w=6; s=1.5` gives `p~2.14, so x ~ 1.7`. Maple sheet:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please explain your second phrase a bit more ("We can see...")? It is not obvious to me...

Comment: @Den I added explanation.

Comment: Thank you, I started putting this into practice and it looks very promising!